# js: check if 2 elements has the same class and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basicly i would like something like, when you click on each div from **object1**, if on **object2** has the same class, do something.

In this case it will scroll until the respective element.

```
<div class='object1'>
   <div class='element 1'></div>
   <div class='element 2'></div>
   <div class='element 3'></div>
</div>

<div  class='object2'>
   <div class='element 1'></div>
   <div class='element 2'></div>
   <div class='element 3'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Where's your code?

Comment: If language is a barrier to explain things clearly, I recommend [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: `if(obj1.hasClass('myclass') && obj2.hasclass('myclass'))`

Comment: Note that in your example, because of the spaces, each child div has two class names. i.e. the first child of object1 has classes "element" and "1". You may not have wanted that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"if on object2 has the same class"* ? `object2` has the same class..? any element inside it has the same class? a particular element inside it has the same class..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when div.element1 is clicked on, you want find div.element1 on object2 and if it exists scroll to it. You can usee something like this:

```
$(".object1 > div").click(function (){
    var class = $(this).attr("class");
    if ($(".object2 > div." + class).length > 0){
         var matchingDivOn2ndObject = $(".object2 > div." + class)[0];

         $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: matchingDivOn2ndObject.offset().top
          }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/fspc4sza/) together with the scrolling:

```
$(".object1 div").on("click", function () {
  var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".object2 div." + classes[1]).offset().top
 }, 1000);
});
```